# Dynamic variable assignment in pure shell without using eval

Tags: shell, security, eval, dynamic-variables

Is there a way to assign arbitrary values to dynamically named variables in pure shell (i.e. `sh`, not `bash`) without using `eval`?

I would like to know if there was a way to avoid using `eval` as it can allow for arbitrary code execution.

`let` seems only to work only for numerical values.

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements? The `declare` command in your accepted answer is not "pure shell", in that it is a `bash` extension, not part of POSIX `sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to `declare`: it allows you to specify variables on the fly.

```
v="test"
declare my$v="hello"
echo "$mytest"
```

Returns:

```
hello
```

You can find more info in [`man declare`](http://ss64.com/bash/declare.html) - I couldn't find a reference to the shell manual.

Comment: @rhlee What did you mean by "pure shell"? `declare` is a `bash` extension, and not available in every POSIX-compatible shell.

Comment: @chepner better comment in the question, because rhlee won't get the notification here.

Comment: @chepner Yes I found out about the differences between pure and non-pure shells yesterday. The script ran fine on cygwin, but gave me `declare: not found` on linux. I came across https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh , which told me to use `local` instead of `declare`. However I got `local: not in a function`, so I wrapped the whole script in a function and called it and everything worked. I think fedorqui's answer still counts as the correct one as I didn't specify a pure shell.